# Searching for a file with letter "o" and number 6

Tags: linux, bash

I have a directory with about 2,000 files with a variety of file names.

I need to print out all the filenames that contain the letter o and have a 6 two spaces to the right from the o. For example:

flow6, tro168, arrow6ish.

Would I use somethings similar to:

```
find -name 'o*6'
```

Comment: @squiguy That doesn't imply "two spaces to the right", i. e. you'll get false positives. Did you mean `ls | grep "o.6"` instead?

Comment: I was just giving an example. I just don't know how to search for the 6 being 2 spaces to the right.

Comment: @H2CO3 Yes, I was going to edit, found that I couldn't and then comment again :)

Comment: @Dhunt90 I just showed you that in my previous comment.

Comment: Great thanks. You can put that as answer if you want and I'll put it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, don't parse `ls` output (as suggested earlier in the thread), instead try this :

```
printf '%s\n' *o?6*
```

Example :

```
$ ls -1
arrow6ish
flow6
o6
oaaaaaaaaa6
tro168

$ printf '%s\n' *o?6*
arrow6ish
flow6
tro168
```

If you need to run a command on the result, [the simplest is](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#ls) :

```
commandX *o?6*
```

that's all the glob magic.

And if you need recursion, use

```
find . -type f -name '*o?6*'
```

---

`ls` is a tool for interactively looking at file information. Its output is formatted for humans and will cause bugs in scripts. Use globs or find instead. Understand why: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

---

Learn more about [glob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob)s

Comment: Yeah I understand that. What I'm trying to do is search for all the files that have that sequence, change their group ownership to etcgroup and then print how many files were changed using wc -l - in one single pipe. I was trying to use ls ~/data/files | grep "o.6" | chgrp etcgroup | wc -l

Comment: `shopt -s nullglob; x=( *o?6* ); chgrp etcgroup "${x[@]}"; echo "${#x[@]} elements founds"`

Comment: I"m not familiar with shopt. If I wanted to serach in the ~/data/files directory would I include it after shopt -s

Comment: I think you should provide some _read_ efforts, I gave you some interesting links.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name "*o?6*"
```

Should achieve what you want. This is preferable to the `printf` solution if the files are contained in nested subdirectories.